# How do I compare accumulator value to specific positive integer in assembly?

Tags: assembly, hex, comparison, fibonacci

I am writing a non-recursive program that calculates the Fibonacci number up to the Nth term in the sequence in the Mac-1 Assembly architecture. All is going fine and well until I reach the point in my function where I need to compare to see if the N value I have loaded into the accumulator is <= 2. However, the only JUMP executions I am given are JNEG (which jumps if the value is negative) and JZER (which jumps if the value is zero).

So my question is if I have:

```
0001  One:  1        // Constant definition
000A  N:    10       // N
```

In the function I can say:

```
800y  LODL  y        // Loading N after its already been placed in the stack by offset y
C0xx  JNEG  Finished // If the number is negative, we are finished
50xx  JZER  Finished // If the number is zero, we are finished
```

But how would I say If N <= 2? I am only given options for negative or zero, but I need to compare if N <= 2 for my base case in my loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

> a ≤ 2 ⇒ a - 2 ≤ 0 ⇒ a - 2 < 0 ∨ a = 0

Both conditions can be tested with the instructions available.

---

If you want to implement `if (a0 <= a1) ... else ...` you can use

```
LODD a0              /Accumulator = a0
SUBD a1              /Accumulator = a0 - a1
jzer _THEN_branch    /Jump to "then branch" if a0 == a1
jneg _THEN_branch    /Jump to "then branch" if a0 < a1

 /Put "else branch" code here

jump _IF_end

_THEN_branch:

 /Put "then branch" code here

_IF_end:
```

---

There are also some examples [here](http://www.johnloomis.org/ece314/notes/carch/node7.html).